# Blob storage on MySQL NDB engine

Tags: mysql, blob, storage, cluster-computing, varbinary

This is blob storage on ndb as per documentation. I want to see if converting blob to varbinary(large value) saves space. But there are places in documentation that says large varbinary is treated same as Blob. Is that right in case of ndb?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html

The NDB storage engine supports variable-width columns. This means that a VARCHAR column in an NDB Cluster table requires the same amount of storage as would any other storage engine, with the exception that such values are 4-byte aligned. Thus, the string 'abcd' stored in a VARCHAR(50) column using the latin1 character set requires 8 bytes (rather than 5 bytes for the same column value in a MyISAM table).

TEXT and BLOB columns are implemented differently in the NDB storage engine, wherein each row in a TEXT column is made up of two separate parts. One of these is of fixed size (256 bytes), and is actually stored in the original table. The other consists of any data in excess of 256 bytes, which is stored in a hidden table. The rows in this second table are always 2,000 bytes long. This means that the size of a TEXT column is 256 if size <= 256 (where size represents the size of the row); otherwise, the size is 256 + size + (2000 * (size - 256) % 2000).

Answer (score 0):

All variants of BLOBs are handled the same way in NDB.
So answer is yes.